# Integrate apitron to c# project

Tags: c#, pdf, apitron

I am having trouble integrating `apitron pdf kit` dll file to my c# project.

I have downloaded the pdf kit from the site and on extraction I got many dll files corresponding to different `DotNet Framerworks` like 2.0, 4.0, 4.5 etc

Mine is 4.0, when I tried to add as reference the dll file corresponding to framework 4.0, it projected an error to me, which is as follows:

> Warning 1  The referenced assembly "Apitron.PDF.Kit" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project. ExtractPDFText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change target framework from [Client Profile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) to full .NET Framework 4.0:

[image]